# Crystal Report + SVN merging branches

Tags: svn, crystal-reports

I'm working on a big C# project that use Crystal Reports to generate pdf, excel and word report files. 
Project is under SVN repository and we have the main trunk and a separate branch.
Every week we use to merge trunk into the branch but .rpt files are problematic to merge due to their binary content.

Is there a tool or a best prectice to manage this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For one of my past project, I used to require CR developer to add the report description to the SVN repository. You can generate it in Crystal Report from the "Export as > Report Definition" menu or something like this. They are text files representing the structure of the reports.

Then with some pre-commit hook scripting, you can require the existence of such a definition for every `rpt` file, would it be for addition or modification.

You should also be able to automate such meta-data generation using something like [RptToXml](https://github.com/ajryan/RptToXml), or maybe [the diff tools supplied by ReportMiner](http://www.reportminer.com/Products/RptDiff.shtml).

This at least address the *diff* problem with the report files. For the *merge* part, maybe you can find a way to import the Report Definition, but at least you should be able to know from where a potential conflict comes from.